# Tkinter issue when removing text fields

Tags: python, tkinter

i am working on a GUI in Tkinter, and i have encountered a wierd issue that i have been struggling to solve.

The goal is to remove and add users from the interface. When a user is added, it is displayed, and when deleted the user should disappear from the GUI.

This is where my issue begins. When only adding and removing one user, everything works fine.
However when two or more users are added, the removal process fails. The removal works as expected on the first try, but when trying to remove any more, the interface does not update. The users get removed from the list as should, but the GUI never updates. Here is my code

```
#anden slet klik virker ikke
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.entries = -1
        self.people = []

        self.names = []
        self.id = []
        self.tlf = []
        self.frames = []

        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    #Create the first two rows of the application
    def create_widgets(self):
        # Row 0: Input boxes
        self.inputName = tk.Entry(self, bd=4)
        self.inputName.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inputID = tk.Entry(self, bd=4)
        self.inputID.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.inputTLF = tk.Entry(self, bd=4)
        self.inputTLF.grid(row=0, column=2)
        # Row 0: "Add" button
        self.addButton = tk.Button(self, text="Add", command=self.AddMember)
        self.addButton.grid(row=0, column=3)

        # Row 1: Labels
        tk.Label(self, text = "Navn", borderwidth = 4).grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="ID", borderwidth=4).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Tlf", borderwidth=4).grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx=30)
        tk.Label(self, text="   ", borderwidth=4).grid(row=1, column=3)

    # What the "add" button does
    def AddMember(self):
        self.people.append([self.inputName.get(), self.inputID.get(), self.inputTLF.get()]) #Add textbox-text to list
        self.entries += 1
        self.updateMembers()


    def updateMembers(self):  # Display new member
        # This is declared to make sure that self.entries is assigned by value, and not by index
        entry = self.entries
        # Add the new name from 'people' to the list of name entries, and display
        self.names.append(tk.Label(self, text=self.people[entry][0], borderwidth=4))
        self.names[entry].grid(row=entry + 2, column=0)
        # -//- but with ids
        self.id.append(tk.Label(self, text=self.people[entry][1], borderwidth=4))
        self.id[entry].grid(row=entry + 2, column=1)
        # -//- but with phone numbers
        self.tlf.append(tk.Label(self, text=self.people[entry][2], borderwidth=4))
        self.tlf[entry].grid(row=entry + 2, column=2)
        # Create a frame to but multiple buttons in one grid-cell
        self.frames.append(tk.Frame(self))
        self.frames[entry].grid(row=entry + 2, column=3)
        #Create such buttons
        removeButton = tk.Button(self.frames[entry], text="X", command=lambda: self.remove(entry))
        msgButton = tk.Button(self.frames[entry], text="SMS", command=lambda: self.sendSMS(entry))
        callButton = tk.Button(self.frames[entry], text="Ring", command=lambda: self.makeCall(entry))
        #Display such buttons
        removeButton.pack(side='top')
        callButton.pack(side = 'right')
        msgButton.pack(side='left')

    def sendSMS(self, sender_id):
        print("SMSMSMSM")

    def makeCall(self, sender_id):
        print("RINGRINGRING")

    def remove(self, sender_id):
        print("")
        print(self.entries)
        self.people.pop(sender_id)  # Remove from the "People" list



        if self.entries >= 0:
            # Un-display the lowest entry
            self.tlf[self.entries].destroy()
            self.frames[self.entries].destroy()
            self.id[self.entries].destroy()
            self.names[self.entries].destroy()
            
            for i in range(self.entries):  # RE-display all current entries (deleted one excluded)
                tk.Label(self, text=self.people[i][0], borderwidth=4).grid(row=i + 2, column=0)
                tk.Label(self, text=self.people[i][1], borderwidth=4).grid(row=i + 2, column=1)
                tk.Label(self, text=self.people[i][2], borderwidth=4).grid(row=i + 2, column=2)

             # Remove deleted user's info in the display lists.
            self.names.pop(sender_id)
            self.id.pop(sender_id)
            self.tlf.pop(sender_id)
            self.frames.pop(sender_id)

        self.entries -= 1  # Decrement size of people
        print(self.entries)


#Actually start the program
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I have been troubleshooting this for hours on end, and have not managed to solve this, so any help is appreciated :D

Comment: You know that in your `self.tlf[self.entries].destroy()` line you always remove the last person. Shouldn't you use `sender_id` instead?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. Can you please [edit] the question and reduce the code down to a [mcve]?

Comment: Also instead of `command=lambda: self.remove(entry)` use `command=lambda entry=entry: self.remove(entry)`. Same goes for the other buttons